# Replacement for YUI grids in YUI3?

Tags: javascript, yui, yui-grids, yui3

YUI3 [deprecated cssgrids](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/cssgrids/), but I don't see a replacement API on the site. How does one layout grids when using YUI3 (in **future** -- for now, I can use yui2 grids of course)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no reason you can't use the [YUI2 Grids](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/grids/) with YUI3. They work fine with the YUI3 CSS Reset & Fonts. A new grid solution for YUI3 is forthcoming according to Luke Smith (he mentioned it in IRC) but until then the YUI2 Grids are still a totally valid option.

Comment: Grids are back in YUI3 now, and they're way better than the YUI2 version.

http://yuiblog.com/sandbox/yui/3.2.0pr1/examples/cssgrids/index.html (until YUI 3.2.0 is official)

Answer (score 2):

YUI3 Grids is now on their site in beta. Completely different from before but looks much more flexible.